# WSDL to Java artifacts

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl

I'm having troubles generating java artifacts from WSDL url. I have tried this post
[link to post](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-wsdl-stubs) and ended up with this config in my pom file

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlUrls>
                        <wsdlUrl>https://tim-erp.com/ERPX_WEB/awws/ErpX.awws?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                    </wsdlUrls>
                    <packageName>com.output</packageName>
                    <sourceDestDir>
                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/
                    </sourceDestDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

but now I get this error
**[ERROR] Invalid wsdl:operation "kasaLogin": its a document-literal operation,  message part must refer to a schema element declaration.**

Few moths ago I have used this link to generate initial artifactes but I've deleted the code and now I can't remember how did it worked.
Now I'm looking for any solution that would work.
**Wsdl when imported to SOAP UI works fine**. I'm using java 11 and Intellij Idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the message, it seems that wsimport is complaining that the message isn't WS-I Basic Profile compliant. Looking at the WSDL, the fields of the body are flat instead of wrapped so it's possible this is what wsimport doesn't like. Have you tried to run [wsimport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) on the command line and pass it the `-version` option to see if you get more details about the error?

Comment: Hey Bogdan, I've managed to resolve this error using axis 2 maven plugin. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use soap ui to see what the message looks like,  then create soap message exactly like what you've seen ,it works fine for me. Here's part of a demo for create a soap message

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
```

....

after creating a soap message, you just send a http or https request with what you'v assembled.

Comment: Yeah, I still need those artifacts, that is my problem, sending message works fine. Do you know how to generate artifacts ?

Comment: you really don't need those artifacts, after creating the soap envelop, it's normal xml formated data inside , just use jackson-databind-xml to assemble wht's inside.